# How do I convert a single view application to a master detail application?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am learning iOS development on xcode6.1 and wish to convert my project to a master detail application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing magical about the templates. It just gives you some stuff for free to start you off. Embed your existing view controller in a navigation controller (Editor->Embed in in the storyboard editor) then add whatever push segues you need.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new project with the template you wish to use, then move any source you wish to keep into it.